# How to lock the position of lines -group of columns-

Tags: beamer

How to fix these columns on their positions?

```
\begin{frame}
\only<1->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4,7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{images/temps_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item E :
\begin{itemize}
\item D.
\item C.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\only<2->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4,7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{images/productivite_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item B.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\only<3->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4,7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=3cm]{images/controle_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item A.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\end{frame}
```

Because, when I click on the down button. I get the last line displayed translated to top and the new line appears on its bottom. Is it possible to make these lines locked at their defined positions from the beginning ? If yes, how to, please ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `\onslide` or `\visible` instead of `\only`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<1->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4.7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{images/temps_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item E :
\begin{itemize}
\item D.
\item C.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\onslide<2->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4.7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{images/productivite_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item B.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\onslide<3->{
\begin{columns}
\column{4.7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=3cm]{images/controle_prob}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item A.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
```

was just to make the example code compilable; do *not* use it in your actual document.